# how change build default type to ssr in next js versrion above 13

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

When I build project and then navigate in app with router.push , next js loads deeply page

After research, I found that if I build the app as runtime or ssr, the situation will be resolved. Now the issue is that every time I build the project, nextjs builds statically or ssg! How to change the default build method in next settings?

```
Route (app)                                Size     First Load JS
┌ ○ /                                      12.1 kB         233 kB
├ ○ /about                                 159 B          78.5 kB
├ λ /course/[id]                           159 B          78.5 kB
├ ○ /profile                               159 B          78.5 kB
├ ○ /select-grade                          10.6 kB         206 kB
├ ○ /setting                               4.23 kB         131 kB
├ ○ /setting/about-us                      5.67 kB         129 kB
├ ○ /setting/appearance                    7.23 kB         124 kB
├ ○ /setting/edit-daily-goal               5.98 kB         222 kB
├ ○ /setting/notifications                 3.65 kB         132 kB
├ ○ /setting/store                         9.21 kB         340 kB
└ ○ /signup                                17.8 kB         161 kB
+ First Load JS shared by all              78.3 kB
  ├ chunks/2443530c-e89e5a309bb1f246.js    50.5 kB
  ├ chunks/8139-d0a2f4f24604508c.js        24.7 kB
  ├ chunks/main-app-7b87f8e8be843a62.js    224 B
  └ chunks/webpack-2c24952a631fdb89.js     2.94 kB

Route (pages)                              Size     First Load JS
─ ○ /404                                   182 B          87.5 kB
+ First Load JS shared by all              87.3 kB
  ├ chunks/main-f380058e96bfe077.js        84.2 kB
  ├ chunks/pages/_app-6b94368279a02b5e.js  196 B
  └ chunks/webpack-2c24952a631fdb89.js     2.94 kB

ƒ Middleware                               23.4 kB

λ  (Server)  server-side renders at runtime (uses getInitialProps or getServerSideProps)
○  (Static)  automatically rendered as static HTML (uses no initial props)
```

i want to  apply " λ  (Server) " to all pages build